# How to combine HighStock stock-chart and HighCharts bubble-chart in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts

Stock chart: [Stock chart link](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line)

Bubble chart: [Bubble chart link](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble)

The highcharts way of combining 2 charts: [Combining 2 charts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types)

The problem is I can render each one separately but I want them to be displayed in the same chart containing both stock chart and bubble chart at the same place as **shown below**.
[image]

Kindly suggest me a way to merge these both charts in the same way as shown OR another way to achieve this kind of chart (This chart has *-ve and +ve X-axis and +ve Y-axis* with labels displaying some data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set two different series type:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }, {
        type: 'bubble',
        data: [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [2, 2, 2]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g0wvpsx4/

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Could you please guide me on how to manipulate the time in Highstock chart according to our need?

Comment: Hi Prakhar Mittal, Of course I will try to  help you, but I have to know what are your requirements. Probably you have to set right x data values: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.data.x

Comment: What I need is to remove the default text input of dates with a date picker from any react library.

Comment: To remove default date input set `inputEnabled` property to `false`. To apply dates from other input, use `setExtremes` method. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qsgyahfz/

Comment: Thanks for this valuable input. But the problem with this solution is I am developing my project in ReactJS and **can't use** *JQuery*. Can you share any other solution for the same issue?

Comment: Hi Prakhar Mittal, you do not have to use jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aj3ewdfk/

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's all I need. Thanks for all the help and guidance.